# Error message: unsupported operand type(s) for ___

Tags: python, windows-7, primes, divide

This program is used to calculate prime numbers and save them to a file. The saving function hasn't been properly programmed yet so please ignore. The program works by comparing an odd number to previous prime numbers. If it is not a multiple of these numbers then it is prime. In theory it should work however when the I try to divide the number by a prime number from the list it returns the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\Archie\Desktop\maths python\prime\prime v1.3.py", line 51, in 
>      primeCheck(num)
>    File "C:\Users\Archie\Desktop\maths python\prime\prime v1.3.py", line 8, in primeCheck
>      check = int(num) / listImport
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'

Can you please either suggest how I can fix this problem or suggest a different approach to the problem.

```
def primeCheck(num):
    divider = 2
    refresh = 0
    firstPoint = 0
    secondPoint = 1
    while refresh == 0:
        listImport = primeList[firstPoint:secondPoint]
        check = int(num) / listImport
        if (check.is_integer()):
            refresh = 1
        else:
            firstPoint = firstPoint + 1
            secondPoint = secondPoint + 1
        if secondPoint > len(primeList):
            file.write(str(num) + "\n")
            print(str(num))
            global x
            x = x + 1
            refresh = 1
            primeList.append


\\        if (int(num)/divider).is_integer():
\\            if divider == num:
\\                file.write(str(num) + "\n")
\\                print(str(num))
\\                global x
\\                x = x + 1
\\                refresh = 1
\\            else:
\\                refresh = 1
\\        else:
\\            divider = divider + 1

global file
repeat = input("How many numbers do you want to add to the existing file?\n")
file = open("Prime results v1.3.txt", "r")
global x
x = 1
num = file.readline()
file.close()
global file
file = open("Prime results v1.3.txt", "a")
num = int(num)

global primeList
primeList = [2]

while x <= int(repeat):
    primeCheck(num)
    num = num + 2

file.close()
```

The area double slashed is a previous approach I tried, which worked, however this way is more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of ways how to improve your code. But the reason for the error is that you get a list when you do this `primeList[firstPoint:secondPoint]`.

More on this topic is nicely explained here in SO question: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

When you want to index only a single item in a list, you can do it by using `my_list[idx]` (note: Python indexes from 0) which returns the item at the position `idx` of list `my_list`.

It seems to me that the difference between `firstPoint` and `secondPoint` is always equal to 1 (if I understand your code well). So you dont have to use secondPoint at all.
Just write `primeList[firstPoint]` and you get the same result as when you use `primeList[firstPoint:secondPoint]`.

There is also an error on the line

`primeList.append`

Which is a function and not a function call. You probably want to do:

`primeList.append(num)`

And another tricky part could be, that if you use Python2.x and not Python 3.0 division of two integers is again an integer (e.g. `4/3 = 0`). 
So I suggest slight modification:

```
check = float(num) / listImport
```

Than `4/3 = 1.3333333333333333` and moreover `is_integer()` function raises an error when called on int (and if you use Python 2.x then `int/int` returns `int` and therefore raises an error.

Example (Python 2.7):

```
>>> 1/4
0
>>> float(1)/4
1.3333333333333333
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `firstPoint` and `secondPoint` to try to and index a particular element of `primeList`. According to your current code, if `primeList = [2,3,5,7]` and `firstPoint, secondPoint = 0, 1`, then you have `listImport = primeList[0:1] = [2]` -- you wind up with a list containing the element you want, which is why it says you can't divide an int and a list.

Instead, you'll want to index into the list. So `primeList[0]=2`, `primeList[1]=3`, and so on. That way you wind up with the actual element, not a slice of the list, and besides that you only need to keep track of one index.

You can read more about Python list operations [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) -- their documentation is comprehensive and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

In line 8 you are trying to divide an integer by an list. This is not defined. What you want is to devide an integer by another integer. Note that `alist[i:i+1]` is still a list. You want `alist[i]`, or yet better, iterate over a list with `for item in list:`.